# How to make Ubuntu Mate headless, and auto-login on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, headless, autologin

1. I know how to [auto login](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/auto-login-to-the-desktop/60) to the Raspberry Pi on start up with the graphical interface using lightdbm.
2. I know how to [make](https://bitbucket.org/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-rpi2/issues/4/boot-to-shell-with-ubuntu-mate-1504-on) the Raspberry Pi "headless".
3. I know how to run a script at start up. (~/.bashrc)

My problem is: I don't know how to make a script that runs at start up that can  auto login to the Raspberry Pi while disabling the Graphical interface in order to make it run headless.

I have found few articles, people use `/etc/inittab` but the file does not seem to be there on Ubuntu mate version. I have looked for a file in `/etc/init/tty1` but it's not there neither.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You need to change the default target to boot into in systemd.

You can boot to the terminal with the following commands -

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target --force
systemctl disable lightdm.service --force
systemctl disable graphical.target --force
systemctl disable plymouth.service --force
```

Replace `disable` with `enable` if you wish to boot to desktop again.

Check this answer out: [Boot to shell with Ubuntu MATE 15.04 on raspberry pi](https://bitbucket.org/ubuntu-mate/ubuntu-mate-rpi2/issues/4/boot-to-shell-with-ubuntu-mate-1504-on)

If you have trouble, dig deeper [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/solved-boot-raspberry-pi-2-image-directly-to-terminal-console/1569/6)